# Is there a way to define path of new action without '/new' in Ruby on Rails routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to define path of new action without '/new' in Ruby on Rails `routes.rb` by writing `resources`?

I would like to define a page of `/p/e/:article_id` as `popular/contacts#new` action.

Then, I wrote below.

```
namespace :popular, path: 'p' do
  resources :contacts, only: [:new], path: 'e/:article_id'
end
```

However, the result of above is this.

```
new_popular_contact GET   /p/e/:article_id/new(.:format)    popular/contacts#new
```

If possible, I would like to use `resources`, But do I have no choice but to use `get` as  below instead of `resources`?

```
namespace :popular, path: 'p' do
  get '/e/:article_id' => 'contacts#new'
end
```

Thank you

Comment: @DaveNewton Look again -- The ID is for the article, not the contact.

Comment: @TomLord Ah, right--completely misread that.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. Instead of routing `e/:article_id` to the new action you really just should put a form on the show action. Of course its possible but its a quirky and suprising solution to a simple problem. The `new` action only exists as a way to display a form - if you have a form on the show action its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter pathnames like below:

```
scope(path_names: { new: 'neu', edit: 'bearbeiten' }) do
  resources :categories, path: 'kategorien'
end
```

Refer: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths

Comment: You can also set this directly on the `resources` method. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments